# How to restrict authenticated users to only access their on profile

Tags: php, laravel

I am stuck with users profile feature, I want only authenticated users to access their own profile only.

User with `id: 1` can only access route `/applicants/profile/1`, otherwise return `404 Not found`?

```
class ApplicantProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Applicant $applicant)
    {
        return view('applicant.show', compact('applicant'));
    }
}
```

```
route::group(['prefix' => 'applicants', 'middleware' => 'auth:applicant'], function() {
    Route::get('/profile/{applicant}', 'Profiles\ApplicantProfileController@show');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chech whether the logged user and the parameter user are the same by using the `Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth` facade like this:

```
public function show(Applicant $applicant)
{
    if (Auth::id() == $applicant->id) {
        return view('applicant.show', compact('applicant'));
    }

    return abort(404);
}
```

Comment: I have tried checking with Auth facade but didn't come close to this. Thank you, it worked :).